# Finding the error of $log_2(1+x)\approx x$ in the sense of uniform norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, computer-science

I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to find the optimal error of (in the sense of uniform norm):
$$log_2(1+x)-x = \sigma , x\in[0,1]$$
If I understand correctly the notion of uniform norm: in this case, since the function is continuous in [0,1], finding the maximum of the function will give me the answer I'm looking for.
However, the following section from a wiki page has a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ multiplying the maximum I found. Can anyone explain where this difference comes from?
[image: taken from "fast inverse square root" - wiki page]
(taken from "fast inverse square root" - wiki page)

Comment: You are correct about the factor, this is easy to check. There might be some context missing. It could be that originally this was the error in computing $\log_2(\sqrt{1+m_x})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what the optimal $\sigma$ here refers to. We are looking for the $\sigma$ that minimises $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |\log_{2}(1+x) - x - \sigma|$, and this is exactly $\frac{1}{2} \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |\log_{2}(1+x) - x|$ if you do the relevant calculus.

Comment: Got it. Thank you